# How to make background transparent using opengles in native code android

Tags: android, opengl-es, vuforia, irrlicht

Iam working on opengles project i want to know how to make background transparent using opengles, here what iam doing right now

```
glClearColor(0,0,0,0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

But it doesnot make my view transparent, in background iam running my camera, so if it get transparent i can see whats on my camera view, As soon as i put these lines in my code, my view get black. I want to know how to make view transparent using opengles 2 in native code.

Comment: @Overv they are doing it in java files, i am asking how to do it in native code (android jni)